# Reducing the size of bounding box using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I am using QGIS 3.24.
I am writing a function to see the which points are intersecting which census_blocks from a polygon layer.

```py
spatialIndex = QgsSpatialIndex(polyLyr_cb)
        
for a_point in point.getFeatures():    #Iterating through nodes 
    geometry = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsGeometry.asPoint(a_point.geometry()))
    bounding_box = geometry.boundingBox()
    intersecting_features = spatialIndex.intersects(bounding_box)
    print(intersecting_features)         
    break
```

Here the output is -
(12894,12895)

But i want to just get one point instead of two. So I want to reduce the size of the bounding box so as to get one specific point.
How can i do it.

Comment: If you use the console to call your `bounding_box` variable, you will probably see that it has no size (`xmin == xmax` and `ymin == ymax`), because it is the bounds of a single point. Therefore, you cannot reduce it. Incidentally, you can skip line 4 in your code as it just goes round in a circle. You can use `bounding_box = a_point.geometry().boundingBox()` instead.

Comment: Still I'm getting 2 intersecting polygons - [14894, 14895] How to fix this

Comment: If you want to limit the result to purely the first intersection, you can use something like `intersecting_polygon = intersecting_features[0]`. However, if you want to select the polygon based on a criterion (such as area, or another attribute), you will have to perform a check on your polygons and select the corresponding feature. If that is the case, I suggest re-wording your question, as what you are aiming for seems to be quite different from your question title.

Comment: Not sure if this would work, but try setting the bounding box to a value instead of getting the value. When using ESRI REST (I know it's not exactly the same) I've been able to set the box to a value that was not the actual bounding box and that seemed to enable me to get that one result.